# Error loading DefaultTemplate.xaml in designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I can't load my projects' DefaultTemplate.xaml file in the designer. (using VS2010 premium, recently reinstalled)
When loading the DefaultTemplate.xaml from the build templates in TFS, I get an error saying that the activity cannot be loaded.
There are errors loading the namespaces. Somehow it cannot find the assemblies needed for TFS.
In the errors list I get about 50 complaints about these namespaces.

I've poked around in it, but never commited any changes. I've tried restoring the original version, but that didn't work.
I've tried replacing the template with the DefaultTemplate.xaml from another project, but I got the same error. I'm at a loss here. How can I fix my VS2010 or template so I can edit it again using the designer?
I can open other projects' DefaultTemplate.xaml files in the designer without any problems.

I suspect that it has to do with some setting in VS2010 or my project somehow not having the right references, but I can't figure out what's wrong or how to solve it.

Comment: What's the error you get? Any design time exception?

Comment: The first error I get says the following: (the others are just like it).
`Error 2 Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built. D:\files\work\Afstuderen Onno Filippo\BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.xaml 4 14 Miscellaneous Files`

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/fdda84d0-6035-40c8-b476-079080b62fb7?prof=required) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/5a52ac23-337b-4c77-913b-5034d202a190) will address your issue.

Edit:

If above doesn't work try below, you may get more descriptive error by using this. This works for windows applications on VS2008. I've never tried this with VS2010. You can debug your devenv.exe instance by another devenv.exe. Below are the steps. Give it a go...

1) Start a second instance of visual studio

2) go the the Tools menu, "Attach to process", select the 'devenv.exe' process, and click the 'attach' button.

3) In the Debug/Exceptions menu Turn on exception catching when first thrown (in the Debug->Exceptions menu).
[image]

4) Open the designer with the debugger attached

5) The second visual studion will break on your error.

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. I had read them both before posting the question. Unfortunately they do not provide the answer for me. The first isn't really a solution. The solution of the second link refers to the first. I've also read Ewald's suggestion in that thread, but it doesn't seem to deal with the problem at hand.

Comment: @Onno : I've edit my answer. That's the only way AFAIK to find the design time errors. But I am not quite sure how it work in your case.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion. It  turned out that the solution was the problem. The last changeset worked ok with my laptop. I reverted to the last changeset of my solution on my work pc and it was ok again.